# How to set the git sparse-checkout with two depth directory?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I try to setting git environment, only fetch some specific directory.

Many people recommend spare-checkout and it is useful.

But still it has some happening.

What I want is that if My project is consisting of two depth directory, like main-sub-sub1&sub2,

then just want to bring sub1 and sub2 without sub i.e. my working directory/sub1 and sub2.

However, it doesn't work like that, result is my working directory/sub/sub1 and sub2.

How do I set more details about sparse-checkout to get what I want.

Or, is there another way?

set git spare-checkout info like

main/sub/sub1
main/sub/sub2